# How to change/replace a 'v' to '\/' using special chars in C# using replace method

Tags: c#, replace

I have a form with a textbox, button and label. Some characters from the text in the textbox should be converted to numbers and some have to be converted to '/' and '|/|'. The last two are the problem i'm facing. I already tried using a @ before the '/' because i found that solution on stackoverflow but it doesn't work.

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tekst = txtText.Text;
    string haxorA = tekst.Replace('a', '4');
    string haxorS = tekst.Replace('s', '5');
    string haxorE = tekst.Replace('e', '3');
    string haxorV = tekst.Replace('v', '\/');
    string havorM = tekst.Replace('m', '|\/|');

}
```

can someone help me to find a solution?

Comment: A char is one character. `\/` are two characters (ignoring the invalid escape sequence). Use strings instead. Read [ask] and research the "problem you're facing", being a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, didn't know i could only use 1 char to replace it. @CodeCaster

Comment: @Baspa: You can use as many chars to replace as you like, as long as you chose the right method, that is replacing a string of length 1 with a string of the length you choose (a string can have length 0 as well, a char is always 1 character long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to replace a char with a string. Change the last two lines to:

```
string haxorV = tekst.Replace("v", @"\/");
string havorM = tekst.Replace("m", @"|\/|");
```

and replace the *string* `v` with the *string* `\/` and the *string* `m` with the *string* `|\/|`.

Note that a char is just one character, `\/` are two characters, which means it's a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked and helped me.